# Android EditText выполнение метода по мере ввода

Tags: android, android-edittext

Хочу реализовать, чтобы по мере ввода текста в EditText выводились значения (наподобие вариантов, в моем случае городов) в ListView.

Но я не могу найти среди слушателей(Listeners) компонента EditText, нужный мне слушатель. Можно ли вообще так сделать? (Данные будут подгружаться с удаленной MySQL) и стоит ли вообще?

Comment: что за компонент EditView, такого в API Android нет

Comment: @pavlofff, должно быть автор имел в виду EditText. В теге указан именно он, хоть и  в самом вопросе пару раз фигурирует некий editview

Comment: @A.Shakhov да, имел ввиду edittext

Comment: смотрели на https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView ?

Comment: @x0r но ведь там можно только предустановленные значения отображать, не грузить же мне в него всю базу городов?

Comment: @danilshik не обязательно. Данные можно подтягивать в адаптере. Вот нашел пример с бд: http://www.zoftino.com/autocompletetextview-dynamic-serach-from-database

Comment: @x0r в приведенном вашем примере, данные подтягиваются со встроенной СУБД SQLite, судя по коду  public void onOpen (SupportSQLiteDatabase db){. У меня же данные грузятся с удаленной MySQL, на что при большом количестве данных будет задержка. Если вы найдете пример именно с MySQL, то тогда соглашусь)

Answer (score 2):

Для установки слушателя поля `EditText` можно установить `TextWatcher`, передав его параметром в метод `addTextChangedListener`:

```
awesomeEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

   }
});
```