# Проверка поля на заполнение android

Tags: android, button, валидация, android-room

У меня есть приложение для логина, и там есть два поля для ввода логина и пароля, и мне нужно вставить проверку на наличие там символов, то есть если одно из полей пустое то кнопка submit не активна а если два заполнены то активна, и соответственно если одно из полей пустое то кнопка тоже неактивна. У меня на данный момент есть такой код:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final Button submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        TextView mResponseTv = findViewById(R.id.tv_response);

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                sendPost();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }


    public void sendPost() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();

        if(titleEt.getText().length()== 0 && bodyEt.getText().length()== 0)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(titleEt.getText().length() > 1 && bodyEt.getText().length()> 4)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).setEnabled(true);
        }


        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https:/.../")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        mAPIService.auth(new Post(a, b)).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Response<Post> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

там есть место где я пробовал вставлять проверку но почему-то она не работает, то есть кнопка просто не работает независимо от того есть ли что то в поле для ввода. Если кто знает где у меня ошибка или знает чем мне помочь буду очень благодарен, так как все найденные мною способы оказались не рабочими.

Comment: Вы хотите по нажатию кнопки проверялось есть ли символы в edittext и  если условие неверное, кнопка (по которой вы нажали), стала бы не активной?
Пользователь добавил символы в edittext, и захотел нажать кнопку (если условие верно), но кнопка не активна. Вам не кажется логика неправильна?
Я думаю вы хотели сделать чтобы по мере ввода в edittext кнопка становилась бы активной/неактивной, но зачем вы это в метод кнопки тогда прописали. 
К тому же у вас всегда отправляется запрос к серверу, даже если символов нет, что не правильно, вам его нужно засунуть в If

Comment: Вам нужно установить слушатель на edittext а не на кнопку. Думаю это можно сделать TextWatcher, передав его параметром в метод addTextChangedListener. Смотрите ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829478/android-edittext-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: что-то типа ontextchanged итд?

Comment: Думаю да, это всего лишь мое предположение, но думаю им можно решить вашу задачу, в методе кнопки оставьте только запрос к серверу (хотя можно и оставить проверку, для лишней безопасности, но тогда код отправки занесите в условие

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идея в том, чтобы подвесить обработчики на изменение текста в editTexts с логином и паролем. Оформляете данный листенер в отдельный "метод", который потом вешаете на loginEditText и passwordEditText.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
        // проверка. Если длина текста < 0 - выключить кнопку авторизации
   }
  });
```

Как только состояние editText изменилось - обработчик срабаывает, и вы можете изменить состояние кнопки. Надеюсь, общая идея понятна.

Comment: а как у меня этот листенер увидит мою кнопку если она инициализирована только в oncreate()  или ее повторно инициализировать в этом методе?

Comment: нужно вынести final Button submitBtn, заменить на private Button submitBtn (вынести ее в заголовок программы). Плюс, небольшой совет. Вы пишите на java, используйте binding, чтобы не писать каждый раз findViewById. Изучите эти либу от гугл, она упростит ваш код